# Spring Integration Gateway Service method not returning upon start/stop

Tags: java, spring-integration, gateway

I created a control channel and a gateway service to send a control message to that channel. However after I call the gateway service method that is supposed to return boolean is not returning after message submission.

Code Snippet:

```
public interface SampleControlService {
     boolean sendControl(String message);
}

....

@Autowired
private SampleControlService sampleControlService;

.....

boolean done = sampleControlService.sendControl("@testAdapter.stop()"); // message gets sent but it is not returning to caller

System.out.println("Done : " + done); // this line doesn't execute


// integration config
<int:channel id="controlChannel"/>
<int:gateway service-interface="com.test.service.SampleControlService" default-request-channel="controlChannel" />
<int:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel"/>
```

However, if I send a message @testAdapter.isRunning() to check the status, it returns as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `void stop()` does not return a result whereas `boolean isRunning()` does; the gateway does not know anything about the method being called; you are "telling" the framework you are expecting a result that will never come.

You can add another gateway method

```
void sendOneWayControl(String command);
```

or add `default-reply-timeout="0"` to the gateway and you will get a `null` return.